# Why does ObjectDataSource require an optional parameter of a function?

Tags: .net, optional-parameters, objectdatasource

This `ObjectDataSource` will return an error when connecting to the following function:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsActiveProductTypes" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetProductTypes" TypeName="MyRepo">
```

Function with optional parameter:

```
Public Function GetProductTypes(Optional ByVal activeOnly As Boolean = True) As IQueryable(Of ProductType)
    If activeOnly Then
        Return MyContext.ProductTypes.Where(Function(pt) pt.Active = True)
    Else
        Return MyContext.ProductTypes
    End If
End Function
```

Here's the error:

> ObjectDataSource 'odsActiveProductTypes' could not find a non-generic
>   method 'GetProductTypes' that has no parameters.

I realize I can make the code work by adding a parameter to the `ObjectDataSource` or I could overload the function but that defeats the purpose of an optional parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's arguably a bug in .NET.

When the data source is attempting to find the method to bind to, it's running [this code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ObjectDataSourceView.cs,1456), where [part of it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ObjectDataSourceView.cs,1500) is checking:

```
if (methodParametersCount != allParameterCount) {
    continue;
}
```

Where `methodParametersCount` is the count of parameters from your method, which in your case will be 1, albeit optional.  Since you haven't given it any parameters to pass to the method, `allParameterCount` is 0, so it continues looking for more methods.

Having not found any, it [ends up](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ObjectDataSourceView.cs,1557) checking to see if it's matched a method.  If not, it again checks to see how many arguments you supplied, and if 0 (as in your case), throws the exception you're seeing:

```
if (allParameterCount == 0) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.ObjectDataSourceView_MethodNotFoundNoParams, _owner.ID, methodName));
}
```

As you say, the simple fix is to create an overload with no parameters.

Comment: I particularly appreciate that you went under the hood and backed your answer with cited sources.